# Rails: How to route to a specific domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-routing

I have the following route defined:

```
constraints( subdomain: "abc" ) do
    resources :sites do
        resources :pages
    end
    resources :domains
end
```

So I can access a page like so: `abc.example.com/sites/1/pages/2`

I want to route **only** the `show` action of the `PagesController` to be accessible like this: `a-different-domain.com/2`

I have many domains and one domain can have many pages. Domains have the column `domain`. This is what I've thought would work:

```
%w(domains).each do |d|
    constraints( host: d.domain ) do
        get "/*structure" => "pages/dashboard/sites/pages#show"
    end
end
```

I am getting the following error:

> undefined method `domain' for "domains":String (NoMethodError)

How can you do that with Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `%w(domains)` is `["domains"]`

You could do this:

```
# routes.rb
Domain.find_each do |d|
  constraints(subdomain: d.domain) do
    get "/*structure" => "pages/dashboard/sites/pages#show"
  end
end
```

For more information: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints